# Linked list is only displaying the head node, not sure why

Tags: java, linked-list

I am doing a linked list project for my class at school. Essentially we are supposed to make a linked list from scratch, and have add, delete, and find commands. No matter how hard I've been trying I cannot seem to get the list to display anything other than the head node. here are my classes starting from node

public class main {

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
        Node focus = new Node();
        String start;
        start = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter 'A' to add an item"
                + "\n" + "Enter 'D' to delete an item\nEnter 'F' to find an item.");
        if (start.equals("a") || start.equals("A")) {
            focus.data = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter an item to ADD");
            list.Add(focus);
            while (focus != null) {
                focus = list.head;
                focus = focus.next;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "your list is\n" + focus.getData());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}
public class Node {

```
String data;
Node next;
Node prev;

public Node(String data, Node next) {
    this.data = data;
    this.next = next;
}

Node() {

}

public void setData(String data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public String getData() {
    return this.data;
}

public void setNext(Node next) {//setnext
    this.next = next;

}

public Node getNext() {
    return next;
}
```

}

public class LinkedList extends Node {

```
Node head;
int listcount = 0;

public LinkedList() {
    this.prev = null;
    this.next = null;
    this.listcount = 0;
}

LinkedList(Node Set) {

}

public void Add(Node n) {
    Node current = this.prev;
    if (current != null) {
        current = this.prev;
        this.prev = new Node();
    } else {
        head = this.prev = new Node();
        current = head;
    }
    listcount++;

}
```

}

```
I think my biggest problem is the "your list is" part. I can't seem to get it to display anything other than the head node. I would really appreciate the help, as this has been giving me a huge headache. :)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why does your LinkedList extends the Node class? It's a linked list not a node. There's nothing coming before and after the linked list. So the linked list has no **prev** and **next**. All the elements are added in the list and the elements are inserted after the **head** node. The **head** of the node has a **prev** and a **next**. In the **Add** method, if the **head** of the list is null (i.e, the list is empty), the new element becomes the **head** of the list. Otherwise, the new node is inserted after the **head**.

```
public class LinkedList {

    Node head;
    int listcount = 0;

    public LinkedList() {
        this.head = null;
        this.listcount = 0;
    }

    public void Add(Node n) {
        Node current = this.head;
        if (current == null) {
            head = n;
        } else {            
            Node prev = null;
            while (current != null) {
                prev = current;
                current = current.next;
            }
            prev.next = n;
        }
        listcount++;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        Node current = this.head;
        while (current != null) {
            builder.append(current.data).append(", ");
            current = current.next;
        }

        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

I added a **toString** method which loops over the list and builds a string with the content from each node.

In the main method there are a few problems. The linked list is initialised only once not every time you select a choice. If you initialise the linked list every time you select something, then the linked list will always be reinitialised and the only node that will contain will be the **head** node after you add the new element.

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String start;
        boolean finished=false;
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList();

        while(!finished) {

            start = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter 'A' to add an item"
                    + "\n" + "Enter 'D' to delete an item\nEnter 'F' to find an item.");

            if (start.equals("a") || start.equals("A")) {
                Node focus = new Node();
                focus.data = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter an item to ADD");
                list.Add(focus);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "your list is\n" + list.toString());
            }
            else {
                finished = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Try to go over the code and understand what is happening and why. Also use pencil and paper to understand the logic.

Comment: Try to go through the code line by line. Use a debugger as well. It's important to understand how the code works.

Comment: yeah, i went through and now i understand. My teacher never explained anything about a to string, and I realize where i went wrong, wrote a bunch of notes too. Was just wondering, do you know any way to make it go in alphabetical order?

Comment: I added the toString method to iterate over the list and extract the content of the nodes. The iteration procedure is a common procedure to traverse a linked list. The easiest way to order it alphabetically is to sort the list when you insert a new node. For instance, the first node in the list has content 'b'. You want to insert node 'a'. Since 'a' is before 'b', then 'a' becomes the prev of 'b' and 'b' becomes the next of 'a'. Also, in this case, 'a' becomes the head of the list.

Comment: If you want to insert 'c', then follow the same procedure. Start from the head node and compare 'a' with 'c'. 'c' is greater so we are moving to the next node (next of 'a'). At 'b', we compare 'b' with 'c'. 'c' is still greater, but since the next of 'b' is null, then 'c' becomes the next of 'b'. End of algorithm.

Comment: Let's assume instead of 'c' we inserted 'd'. Now our list is 'a','b','d'. We want to insert 'c' in the list. We follow the same procedure. Start from the head node and compare the content of the node with the element you want to insert. As long as this is greater, move to next node. When you reach 'd', then 'c' is less. So the prev of 'd' becomes the prev of 'c', and the next of 'c' becomes 'd'. There are many tutorials available (youtube as well) that explains this procedure. Also, if the answer was useful to you, please confirm/upvode as an accepted answer to your question.

Comment: tried to edit my add function using compare to, still get errors.  public void Add(Node n) {
        Node current = this.head;
        if (current == null) {
            head = n;
        } else {
            Node prev = null;
            while (current != null) {
                if(current.getData() != null && current.getData().compareTo(new Node) > 0){
                    break;
                }
                prev = current;
                current = current.next;
            }
            prev.next = n;
        }
        listcount++;
    }

Comment: sorry, it doesn't paste properly in here.